# Event data for plotly (scattergeo) maps in R Shiny

Tags: r, maps, plotly, shiny

I'm building a shiny app and I'm having some trouble with the plotly map event data. I have created a plotly scatterplot in the past and defined a 'key' variable within the plot_ly function. If I clicked on a point in the scatterplot, the key would be extracted and the key would be used to subset a dataframe and produce a subsequent plot. I'm following the same format in the code below, but the key isn't being stored in the event data. The event data only contains the 'curveNumber' and the 'pointNumber'. It seems to work for the choropleth map found here: https://plot.ly/r/shinyapp-map-click/ but I can't get it to work for 'scattergeo'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("My Shiny App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("idnum", label = h3("ID #"), 
                   value = 3)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("map"),
      verbatimTextOutput("click")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$map <- renderPlotly({

    df <- data.frame(id = c(3,6,20,35), lat = c(30.67,32.46,37.83,29.62), lon = c(-97.82, -62.34, -75.67, -85.62))

    sub <- df[which(df$id == input$idnum),]

    g <- list(
      scope = 'north america',
      showland = TRUE,
      landcolor = toRGB("grey83"),
      subunitcolor = toRGB("white"),
      countrycolor = toRGB("white"),
      showlakes = TRUE,
      lakecolor = toRGB("white"),
      showsubunits = TRUE,
      showcountries = TRUE,
      resolution = 50,
      projection = list(
        type = "miller",
        rotation = list(lon = -100)
      ),
      lonaxis = list(
        showgrid = TRUE,
        gridwidth = 0.5,
        range = c(-140, -55),
        dtick = 5
      ),
      lataxis = list(
        showgrid = TRUE,
        gridwidth = 0.5,
        range = c(20, 60),
        dtick = 5
      )
    )

    plot_ly(sub, lon = ~lon, lat = ~lat, key = ~id, text = ~paste(id), hoverinfo = "text",
            marker = list(size = 10),
            type = 'scattergeo',
            locationmode = 'USA-states') %>%
      layout(title = 'Locations', geo = g)
  })

  output$click <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    if (is.null(d)) "Click events appear here" else d
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to get your key is to replace:

```
sub <- df[which(df$id == input$idnum),]
```

with

```
sub <- df[which(df$id == input$idnum),] 
rownames(sub) <- sub$id 
key <- row.names(sub)
```

it looks like `key` is working with rownames.

Comment: Now I can see the key in the event data when I click on a point. However, the key in the event data for id 20 only returns '2' not 20 and for id 35 it returns 3 not '35'. Does that happen for you as well? I have no idea why it would only return the 1st digit.

Comment: this might be related https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/505. In your example, when I replace id=35 with id=40, 4 is given for the key. It looks like the second unit is cut off.